# Google AdWords and google_conversion_value

Tags: google-ads-api

I have online shop application, and I integrated it with Google AdWords, by adding proper script into web application.

Problem I have, is that Value on Google's Analysis control panel page is 0, despite the thing that I do have Conversions (many-per-click) with value of 12.

Code I integrated looks like this:

```
var google_conversion_id = <number is here>;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "<label is here>";
var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $charge; ?>;
```

I added those lines (with several more JS lines required for Google AdWords) into last page, when payment has been made on my webshop.

PHP variable $charge have value of sold order.

Despite all of those, my Value is still 0. Can you help me waht I'm doing wrong, and how can I get proper value for it?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the PHP output with double quotes like so:

```
var google_conversion_value = "<?php echo $charge; ?>";
```

so that the rendered output looks like:

```
var google_conversion_value = "150";
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried quotes a while back and it did not fix the problem. I'm curious to know if the original poster found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The value can be either in quotes or not - it doesn't matter.

I am not an expert on PHP but from what little I do know is that it looks ok here.  The easiest way to check is to get the Google Tag Assistant extension for Google Chrome that will let you check on the value that is being sent back to Google: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

Using the extension when your conversion tag fires lets you see the values that are actually sent back and so you can confirm if the value is correctly being set.

If it does look like the value is being sent back ok, it would be best to wait at least 72 hours to verify that the value is appearing inside AdWords.